# Brain Tree Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Braintree"

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

I am using Braintree in my app. But after getting token from my server and trying to initilise the Braintree object then it is showing the following error(i am using xCode v.7 and base SDK iOS 9.0 with PODS),

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Braintree", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WZBrainTreeDemoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When i remove this code it works but then it presents controller as nil,

this is my code to initialise and present controller,

```
       strToken = dictResponse[@"braintree_client_token"];


         // If you haven't already, create and retain a `Braintree` instance with the client token.
         // Typically, you only need to do this once per session.
         self.braintree = [Braintree braintreeWithClientToken:strToken];

         // Create a BTDropInViewController
         BTDropInViewController *dropInViewController = [self.braintree dropInViewControllerWithDelegate:self];
         // This is where you might want to customize your Drop in. (See below.)

         // The way you present your BTDropInViewController instance is up to you.
         // In this example, we wrap it in a new, modally presented navigation controller:
         dropInViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                                               target:self
                                                                                                               action:@selector(userDidCancelPayment)];

         UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dropInViewController];
         [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can you please try Enable Bitcode to NO ? Target->build settings-> enable bitcode

Comment: What error now you are getting?

Comment: same error i am getting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally the error has been solved, Need to check complier flags for pods and project

Comment: can you please elaborate where you added the flags ? what flags you have added

Comment: Can you please share your solution?

Comment: Can you PLEASE share your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Change OTHER_LDFLAGS flag for both the projects i.e. Pod Project and your own project to $(inherited)